# Prestashop carrier unavailable at checkout.Shows error

Tags: configuration, checkout, backend, prestashop, online-store

Well I have a strange problem. I set up my prestashop carrier with the settings as in the image:[image: carrier configuration at back office]

Now when I checkout with an address belongs to country India( Which is in Asia continent), it says

> There is 1 error
>
> 1. There are no carriers that deliver to the address you selected.

Whats wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First go to shipping tab on header..then click on shipping submenu..Then scroll the page and come to bottom of the page.Now you can see ..Fees Tab.Select the carrier there and check whether Zone or range properly set for this carrier..i can share images with u but i dont have 10 reputations to share images..so sorry..but check in that way..that will help

or i think you have not set Price Range or Weight Range for your carrier..goto the shipping tab and click on Price Range or Weight Range submenu..and click on add new button to add Price Range or Weight Range..after that it will definitely show in the frontend